# Why are in-house counsels not allowed to defend a defendant?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

In the last John Gotti trial, the prosecutors successfully argued Bruce Cutler was an in-house counselor for John Gotti. The result was Cutler was not allowed to defend John Gotti at trial.

Why are in-house counsels not allowed to defend a defendant at trial?

Comment: The facts in this question are not sufficient to provide an accurate answer because there is not a generally rule prohibiting an in house counsel from serving as a criminal defense attorney for an individual and a report that says that is glossing over some key context or details. Could you provide a link to the news report or case?

Comment: Thanks @ohwilleke. The program that said it was [Mobsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobsters_(TV_series)), which is a TV documentary series airing in the US.